# Is it possible to run UNIT TEST with Cypress standalone version similar to how Jasmine does it? (in browser)

Tags: unit-testing, jasmine, cypress

Cypress allows for GUI testing in browser as well as Unit Testing using the NodeJS installation version.
But I was wondering if the standalone version, aside for UI testing, it also allows for Unit testing.
I don't seem to find any information in regards.

I am working on a website project that uses **plain HTML + JS**, meaning that there is **no NodeJS involved** nor anything similar.
I need to write some Unit tests for it.

If I was to use Jasmine, that provides a simple inline script linking such as `<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jasmine-{#.#.#}/jasmine.js"></script>`.

But I'm not sure how it is done in Cypress, or if it is even possible.
It would be handy to be able to do Unit test and UI test with the same testing library.